# Given an array $A$ of length $N<10^6,$ how many subarrays have $\text{max}(A[x:y]) - \text{min}(A[x:y]) {\le} K$?

Tags: computer-science

Given any K and an array of length $N$ what is the most efficient way to find the number of unique subarrays that satisfy this constraint? I believe there is an $O(N)$ solution using monotonic queues but am unsure of the specifics. Unique refers to the range of the original array that the subarray covers.

Comment: The question is worded in a confusing way since it appears $A$ refers both to the array and any subarray.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: What is uniqueness? [2,5,3] and [2,6,3] ,are these unique?

Comment: What's the source of this question?

Comment: @MayankDeora yes those are unique.

Comment: @joriki The source of the question is https://dmoj.ca/problem/dmopc15c6p5.

Comment: [1,3,5] and [1,5] ,are these unique or same?